# Calculate the number of model grid cells covering a specific country

Tags: models, numerical-modelling, grid-spacing

What is the best method of calculating the number of model grid cells (e.g. of climate models) covering a specific country? For example, if I wanted to know how many 2 degree grid cells are in the United Kingdom, how would I go about it? At present I use the mapping toolbox in matlab and add a 2 degree grid and calculate manually. Is there a better way of doing this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have land mask and borders of the grids. From the whole grid loop over a rectangular shape compassing UK but no other countries and for each cell check the land mask.

Comment: Be aware that some models use non-equirectangular grids.

Comment: Do you have the countries outlines in matlab as a vector? Or an image?

Comment: I would do it in a geographic information system and this question might be better answered in https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple 'back of the napkin' idea for Python:

1. Get a shapefile of the borders and use Python to create a polygon of the borders.
2. Use mpl_toolkits to convert the climate model to X and Y coordinates
3. [Check to see if the model grid points are within the Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python)